# How is Edge's "Detach from Edge" sidebar feature implemented?

Tags: windows, winapi, window, microsoft-edge

Microsoft Edge features an option in the sidebar to "Detach from Edge", which docks the sidebar to the border of the screen.
More interestingly though, it also makes other windows aware of this, by reducing their size even when those windows are maximized.

Even when using external software like [Window Grid](http://windowgrid.net/), the grid seems to be aware of the sidebar being docked to the screen border, and is reduced in size accordingly.

So there seems to be an additional Windows API in play here, however I was unable to find any information about the details.

The best I could come up with is manually positioning and sizing a borderless window, as well as making it show always on top.

But there must be more API calls in play to allow for maximized windows to work properly as well.

Comment: [Application Desktop Toolbars](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/application-desktop-toolbars)